# How can I get the user name who invoked the method of COM server?

Tags: c++, com, dcom

I have a COM server written in C++ running on some computer in a network. Clients may perform remote calls to it from the other computers. Can I determine the name of the user which make the call to the COM-methods from the methods itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by calling [CoImpersonateClient()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from within a COM method.  One you're impersonating, you can then call [GetUserNameEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to fetch the user name.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to get the SID of that user?