# How can I get the SID of the user who invoked the method of COM server?

Tags: c++, com, dcom

I already asked about how to get the user name.
[How can I get the user name who invoked the method of COM server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486348/how-can-i-get-the-user-name-who-invoked-the-method-of-com-server)
Now I need to get the SID too. How do I do this?

The OpenProcessToken approach doesn't work because this function fails with ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**
In order to do this, the client should allow the server to get its information by configuring the proxy with CoSetProxyBlanket API as shown below:

```
HRESULT hr;
if(FAILED(hr = ::CoSetProxyBlanket(
            unk // An interface the client uses to access the com server
            , RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT
            , RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT
            , NULL
            , RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT
            , RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_DELEGATE // This flag should be *_DELEGATE or *_IMPERSONATE or *_IDENTIFY
            , NULL
            , EOAC_DYNAMIC_CLOAKING)))
    throw com_exception(hr, "Failed to set proxy blanket");
```

Then being impersonated (CoImpersonateClient) you may access the user's token with OpenThreadToken.

**END OF UPDATE**

And after that you may use GetTokenInformation API as follows:

```
DWORD tokenSize = 0;
::GetTokenInformation(token, TokenUser, NULL, 0, &tokenSize);

....
TOKEN_USER *tokenInfo; // should point to a memory location of size tokenSize.
....
if(::GetTokenInformation(token, infoClass, tokenInfo, tokenSize, &tokenSize) == FALSE)
    throw win32_exception(::GetLastError(), "Failed to obtain token information");
```

tokenInfo will contain the field User.Sid of type PSID.